# Magento 2 Cart Price rule conditons: If items with attribute subtotal is greater then X

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

i'm looking for a specific way to solve a cart price rule condition. The resultion action itself is not relevant and already solved in my case.

I have different product types, specified by an attribute.
lets call them Type X and  Z

**Goal:
If the subtotal of all items with attribute X is greater then 200,00, then apply rule**

So far i could only find:

- If amount of all X items is...
- If price in cart of one item is...
- If subtotal of cart is...

None of these and combinations of them solve the problem.

Example:

- Position 1:
  Item SKU 123, Type X, Amount 2, Price: 50,00 -> Subtotal of 100
- Position 2:
  Item SKU 124, Type X, Amount 100, Price: 0,50 -> Subtotal of 50
- Position 3:
  Item SKU 889, Type Z, Amount 1, Price: 1500,00 -> Subtotal of 1500

In this case the rule should **not** apply since the total of the X items are only 150,00.

Increasing the amount of Position 1 or 2, could activate the rule, if the subtotal reaches  atleast 200,00

- The amount of the Type X items is useless to determine the price.
- The price of one item in the cart is useless if there are multiple items of Type x
- The subtotal of the cart is useless since other items, likeType Z, are to be ignored

Long story short:
Any possible core feature way to solve this? Or does this need an extansion?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can create a cart price rule that will satisfy your needs with the default Magento install. I just tried this on an Open Source 2.4.1, but none of the *'cart attributes'* in Conditions section or *'cart item attributes'* in Action section does the trick.

The only thing partially solving the problem is *'row total in cart'* condition in the Action section, but that would work only if you increased qty of Position 1 until its row total reaches 200 OR if you increased Position 2 until its row total becomes 200. There is no option to take into account multiple row totals together (Position 1 + Position 2).

So I think you need a customization here (either you develop it or you purchase a module that could do that).